# Nginx not serving static files in production with whitenoise

Tags: python, django, nginx

Everything looks like it should work, but I get a 404 error in console for all static files including css, js and images. What am I doing wrong? Everything else seems to work just fine.

***nginx.conf***

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.${NGINX_HOST};
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${NGINX_HOST}/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/${NGINX_HOST}/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/${NGINX_HOST}/chain.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /static {    
        autoindex on;    
        alias /myapp/collectedstatic/; 
    }

    location /media/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /myapp/media/;
    }
}
```

***settings.py***

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
...

MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'collectedstatic')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: `location /` block must come after more specific locations. Nginx goes through locations sequentially, `location /` matches everything, skipping `location /static` and `location /media`

Comment: /static in location but /static/ in STATIC_URL .

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add a volume for static files to `my docker-compose.yml`

```
  nginx:
    ...
    volumes:
      - static-volume:/app/collectedstatic
      - media-volume:/app/media
```

Comment: I take it this solved the problem for you?